# Unable to import JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder in spring boot 1.5.7 version

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to write below code in the spring boot 1.5.7 version.

```
@Bean
        public JdbcBatchItemWriter<WriterSO> writer(DataSource dataSource, ItemPreparedStatementSetter<WriterSO> setter) {
            return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<WriterSO>()
                    .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
                    .itemPreparedStatementSetter(setter)
                    .sql("insert into writer (id, fullName, randomNum) values (?,?,?)").dataSource(dataSource).build();
        }
```

but unable to use or import the package belongs to JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder. does this package is not available in springboot 1.5.7?

Below is my pom.xml which is using in the project :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.batch</groupId>
    <artifactId>Batchwithpostgres</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Batchwithpostgres</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project
```

>

Any suggestions to write alternate code whcich works in springboot 1.5.7

Comment: This package come from Spring-Batch.

Comment: @Zorglube, yes you are correct I have added the spring batch dependency in the pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

According to JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.1.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/builder/JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder.html), it was added in version 4, and Spring Boot 1.5.7 uses version 3 of Spring Batch, therefore it is not available to you.

You can use the constructor and set all the required fields:

```
@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<WriterSO> writer(DataSource dataSource, ItemPreparedStatementSetter<WriterSO> setter) {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<WriterSO> jdbcBatchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    jdbcBatchItemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<WriterSO>());
    jdbcBatchItemWriter.setItemPreparedStatementSetter(setter);
    jdbcBatchItemWriter.setSql("insert into writer (id, fullName, randomNum) values (?,?,?)");
    jdbcBatchItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return jdbcBatchItemWriter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 1.5.7 brings Spring Batch 3.0.8 which does not provide builders for item readers and writers.

These builders were [introduced in Spring Batch 4](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/whatsnew.html#whatsNewBuilders) which can be consumed using Spring Boot 2.x.